# using verb with a specified time

Tags: verbs, prepositions, adverbs

I have a sentence:

"I will be dead by soon"

And there is my question. Can I use some action adding an adverb with "by" like that. I know that "I will be dead by noon" will do, but what about this one?

And I'm sorry if there are any grammar mistakes in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preposition *by* has a specific meaning with time expressions:

> **by** *prep*
>   6. Not later than: *by 5:30 pm.*
>   <sup>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/by)</sup>

If you use it, then the time expression used has to be specific, not vague or indeterminate like *soon*.

> I will be there by ten o'clock.
>   I will be there by the time you are ready to leave.
>   I will be there by Friday.

Just ask yourself if the time expression being used works with the preposition:

> I will be there not later than soon. (?)

This is grammatically possible, of course, and could be used in a flippant remark, but for most usages it would just sound odd or foreign.